# ошибка подсчета кол-во символов

Tags: php, strlen

```
id0 => 3 символа
@id => 3 символа
@0 => 2 символа
@id0 => 10 символов
```

как это возможно?
почему 4 символа стали вдруг 10?

использую `mb_strlen()`

Comment: `var_dump(mb_strlen('@id0'));` вывод `int(4)`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo bin2hex($tvoya_peremennaya);
```

и смотри какие там у тебя невидимые символы.
Какой-нибудь бом с пререводом строки

Comment: да, я сначало обрезаю ее через mb_substr(), а потом еще и перевожу в explode();

Comment: попробуй для разнообразия написать какую-ниудь осмысленную фразу

Comment: да, спасибо, по какой-то причине через эту функцию вот это 5b6964307c406964305d. да, интересно, почему это вдруг так. а что мне с этим делать?

Comment: да, знаете, почему то @id0 это вот это [id0|@id0]